# Grunt not installed, but already exists

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I am trying to set up grunt for a web build. When I run `npm install -g grunt-cli` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt' -> '/usr/local/bin/grunt'
```

But if I try to run a grunt talk, I get this error:

```
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

I have tried uninstalling grunt with `npm uninstall -g grunt-cli` but it does nothing. I'm at a loss here. How do I remove that version of grunt (that somehow doesn't exist) and reinstall globally?

Comment: Have you installed grunt locally in your project as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `grunt-cli` to your `PATH` after you run `npm install -g grunt-cli`:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
nano .bash_profile
```

and add this line in the end:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin:$PATH
```

and run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
grunt --version
```

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grunt-command-not-found/